# How to run ABAQUS python script from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, abaqus

I am trying to use Visual Code Studio for editing and running Python scripts for ABAQUS (finite element software using internal Python 2.7 interpreter with a lot of libraries).

The standard situation is that I run this command from Windows cmd prompt

abaqus cae noGUI="myscript.py"

==========================================================

EXPLANATION:

The command "abaqus" is a reference to this batch file

C:\SIMULIA\Commands\abaqus.bat

containing

```
@echo off
"C:\SIMULIA\Commands\abq2018.bat" %*
```

and the latter batch file abq2018.bat contains this

```
@echo off
setlocal
set ABA_COMMAND=%~nx0
set ABA_COMMAND_FULL=%~f0
"C:\SIMULIA\CAE\2018\win_b64\code\bin\ABQLauncher.exe" %*
endlocal
```

This is a standard configuration used for ABAQUS software.

==========================================================

Normally, I edit the Python scripts in PSPad and hit F9 which runs the edited script using the macro (therein called Highlighter)

"c:\SIMULIA\Commands\abaqus.bat" cae nogui="%File%"

and everything is perfect.

I tried to set up a similar "one click to run" scenario in Visual Studio Code by playing with "Workspace", "Interpreter", "launch.json" and "python.pythonPath" settings but without any success. The default Python interpreter 3.7 works normally for standard Hello-world etc. scripts.

My goal is to use the debugging features in Visual Studio Code...

Thanks for any help
Robert

Comment: What effect do you expect? Please provide us with minimal examples of your expectations.

Comment: I hoped I wrote everything necessary. My workflow would ideally be as follows: open script in VS Code, set breakpoint(s), hit F5 to run and wait for response from Abaqus (check errors in the code). If Abaqus does not allow the breakpoint functionality then I would at least run the script and wait for response (read log in terminal etc.).

Comment: -Have you tried to debug ordinary python scripts without using ABAQUS python script? Does it work?

Comment: Yep, that works as expected. What is needed to be done in my case (I assume) is to set all the paths and settings but there are no real examples on the web.

Comment: I noticed that you have Python2 and python3. Which version of python are you using? If the python you are using is python3, the script used for testing also needs to be python3.

Comment: @Robert did you find a solution? I would be really interested in being able to set up a breakpoint within a python script used in my Abaqus simulation. Unfortunately, I have not found any command-line solutions. Everything I find suggests to use `abaqus pde` which is kinda inconvenient IMHO as the abaqus pde GUI has to be launched every time, unless I missed something.

Comment: @MarcoMag In short, not yet. After some more digging I found out that there is actually a functional Python installation in the SIMULIA folder. However, when using this Python, there are no Abaqus libraries *.py available for import because they are in the precompiled(?) versions *.pyc (several dozens of files).

Comment: They can be imported "by force" using "marshall" command as some binary piece of code but since one/each library depends on another (or many other) library(-ies) it would be necessary to find out the whole hirearchy (the tree-like structure) of dependencies and import the *pyc files one by one in the correct order (from the lowest level up) so that the next import already has all the prerequisities...

Comment: The ABAQUS executable surely knows how to use that Python installation and how to import the *.pyc libraries but that remains a hidden secret for us users. I guess this is the only way to use real Python in the Visual Studio Code and playing with breakpoints and other tools...

Comment: Or maybe someone can do some reverse-engineering and turn the *.pyc libraries back to *.py files. Then everything would be pretty straightforward. But probably it could be a bit illegal?

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is asked almost two years ago, if somebody is looking to use Visual Code Studio for editing and running Python scripts for ABAQUS, see pyabaqus.

Documentation:
https://pyabaqus.haiiliin.com/

Comment: Thanks John, it looks like an interesting tool. However, it does not say how to use it with Visual Code Studio. Do you use it together? I was unable to "tell" VCS where Abaqus is installed and how to run it. I am able to run standard Abaqus script from command line or e.g. from PSPad where the setting is easy. The pyabaqus is just a library with type hints that help user write the code easily, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I use it with VS Code and I am able to run it direcly from VSC. I have python 3.11 and installed pyabaqus package. You don’t tell VSC the location of abaqus instead you add the .bat file to path. The Pyabaqus finds the location of Abaqus. This package is not specific to VSC and python interpreter should work. I didn’t see any type hints tough.

From pyabaqus doc:

“
Setup your Abaqus Environment
In order to use Abaqus command to execute the Python script and submit the job, you need to tell pyabaqus where the Abaqus command is located. Usually, Abaqus command locates in a directory like this:

C:/SIMULIA/Commands/abaqus.bat
You can add the directory C:/SIMULIA/Commands to the system environment variable Path, or you can create a new system variable named ABAQUS_BAT_PATH, and set the value to the file path of the Abaqus command, i.e., C:/SIMULIA/Commands/abaqus.bat. “

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here in 2023.

Some answers suggested the library [pyabaqus](https://pyabaqus.haiiliin.com/), which has been replaced by the library [abqpy](https://docs.abqpy.com/en/stable/).

The goal of the library is only to provide type hints and also documentation/autocompletion to better write the code in a python 3.x environment, but it has some tools to run the code as well and to pass some arguments that can be useful for debugging (see [environment variables](https://docs.abqpy.com/en/stable/envvars.html#environment-variables) and the [command line interface](https://docs.abqpy.com/en/stable/cli.html#command-line-interface))

---

To use it in VSCode, just install the library in your python 3.x environment like any other package:

```
pip install abqpy
```

Now, when you run your script in the python 3.x interpreter (in VS Code, just press the "play button" on the editor), the script will run in Abaqus CAE interpreter, without graphical interface.

---

##### OBS:

If you `abaqus` command is not installed, you will need to install it or to declare where it is installed with the environment variable `ABAQUS_BAT_PATH`.

From the docs:

> Make sure the `abaqus` command is available in the command line (i.e.,
> you can run `abaqus` in the command line), otherwise, add a new system
> variable named `ABAQUS_BAT_PATH`, and set the value to the file path
> of the Abaqus command, for example, `C:/SIMULIA/Commands/abaqus.bat.`